# Disabing and enabling Events programmatically for Controls of the same type

Tags: c#, events

I have to following three CheckBoxes:

```
CheckBox chk1=new CheckBox();
CheckBox chk2=new CheckBox();
CheckBox chk3=new CheckBox();
```

Each of them have different EventHandlers:

```
chk1.CheckChanged+=chk1_CheckChanged;
chk2.CheckChanged+=chk2_CheckChanged;
chk3.CheckChanged+=chk3_CheckChanged;
```

Now I want to do some fancy stuff that requires that the events are disabled temporarily. This is the code I intend to use:

```
foreach (var checkbox in Controls.OfType<CheckBox>()) {
  var currentEvent=checkBox.CheckChanged; // Should contain chk1_CheckChanged , ... etc.
  checkBox.CheckChanged -=currentEvent;
  checkBox.IsChecked=true;
  checkBox.CheckChanged +=currentEvent;
}
```

This does *not* work because I cannot simply assign the EventHandler to a variable. But how could something like a dynamic Event Switch Off/On be done?

(I am aware that I could use the same eventHandler for all three CheckBoxes and simply disable that but the actions of these three are quite different.)

Comment: Why not set a flag `ignoreCheckChanged` or whatever, and check that in the handlers?

Comment: That feels a bit "dirty" to me. (but that is a purely subjective thought)